# Adding folders to the sidebar of a CFileDialog

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Is there any way to add folders to the sidebar in an MFC CFileDialog? (You know, the bar with shortcuts to "Recent Documents", "My Documents", etc. on the left side of the dialog.) Note that I do not mean that I want the user to have to hack the registry or something to permanently add folders to the sidebar system-wide, I'm talking about having my program add a folder to the side-bar for its own file dialogs. So far my research leads me to believe that for XP I can create a custom dialog and replace the side-bar with my own side bar that has the folders in it, but this won't work on Vista (and by extension Windows 7 I'm assuming). So does anyone know a, preferably low pain, way to add folders to that side-bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Since Vista there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776913(VS.85).aspx) is the [`IFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775966(VS.85).aspx) which have the [`AddPlace(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775946(VS.85).aspx) method.
You will need to write a wrapper that will use CFileDialog (On XP) or IFileDialog (Vista and up).